# Forcing Excel (x86) VBA code to connect to ODBC (x86) on Win7 x64

Tags: oracle, excel, odbc, siebel, vba

We run a VBA script through excel to update a Siebel database, works perfectly in x86 OS but not in x64. Obviously all the files are x86.

The code is throwing an error:
[4096] An Oracle database error has occurred. Possibly the database name is invalid.

The correct connection is definitely referenced correctly (its loaded from a cfg file setup for the actual Siebel applcation, which works fine)

The ODBC connection is shown in the odbcad32 applications (the x86 version not x64)

Through Siebel we can force it to run x86 with a parameter, is there anyway we can force excel to connect to the x86 connection?

Comment: `Obviously all the files are x86.`  Obviously.

Comment: If you have a 64-bit ODBC connection, I would remove it.  Maybe rename it, but better to remove it.  32-bit Excel has to talk to 32-bit ODBC, and truth be told 64-bit doesn't buy you anything on the client side.

Comment: I have completely removed all 64-bit connections just to be safe, even deleted the registry values for it, still won't pickup the 32-bit ones

Comment: Is your Excel 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: It is 32 bit, I've just done a fresh install of all components and still having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use 32bit version of Excel. And have 32bit drivers for the database. I am using a similiar vb macro in excel and this still works for me.

Years ago, I based my custom excel sheet on this [Sel2xl.xls](http://www.livecharts.co.uk/dukascopy/Sel2XL.xls) file , and modified on it. It connects to ODBC via DSNs, and it still works till date. Try and test this on your instance, you can see the macro code if it works.

Comment: That's the thing, I am definitely using 32bit excel and 32bit drivers. Are you running a 64bit os?

Comment: Yes @daniel.henley, I am on Win7-64bit. But I got excel and oracle drivers 32 bit installed, because siebel.exe and tools.exe are all 32 bit. My macros  work fine.

Comment: I'm definitely using the same software then. Are you using the Siebel Oracle80 driver for the dsn? My DSN is currently pointed to the fin2000\bin\seor815.dll, and its working fine for tools and siebel connections, just not in excel. 

Have you connected to the siebel database by loading the cfg file? Documentation for it is here [link](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwi-3rG-nNvOAhWQq5QKHc3rC44QFggoMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FE14004_01%2Fbooks%2FPDF%2FOIRef.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE2G3AuItagZm6e1i7MFyI_eaRSbw&sig2=BIodgnDBEpZ2BCtw3wBo3Q)

Comment: Hi again Ranjith.

The excel file you attached allows direct modification of the database, but what we are currently using is the COM Data Server, documented here [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E05553_01/books/OIRef/OIRefProgramming22.html). No matter what I do I still can't get it working.

The reason we use this is any modifications that we make are made as a front end Siebel user, which means all business rules and such are followed, and the SiebelDataServer.ApplicationObject gives a lot of functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a few months late to the party, but based on a comment on an answer above it looks like you are trying to use the custom DataDirect Oracle driver that comes packaged with Siebel.  You can't use that outside of the Siebel software because it requires a license key that only the Siebel software can provide.  Try it with your own DSN using the plain old Oracle ODBC driver.